# Create multiple folders within multiple S3 buckets with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking to create one S3 terraform module which can take list of bucket names and folder names to be created inside all those buckets.
For e.g. in my S3 module main.tf. I have

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "folders" {
    count = var.create_folders ? length(var.s3_folder_names) : 0
    bucket  = element(aws_s3_bucket.s3bucket.*.id, count.index)
    acl    = "private"
    key    = format("%s/",var.s3_folder_names[count.index])
    source = "/dev/null"
}
```

I am calling this module as given below:

```
variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type = list
  description = "List of S3 bucket names"
default = ["bucket1","bucket-2"]
}
variable "s3_folder_names" {
  type        = list
  description = "The list of S3 folders to be created inside S3 bucket"
  default=["folder1/dev","folder2/qa"]

}
module "s3" {
  source = "../../../gce-nextgen-cloud-terraform-modules/modules/s3"
  create_folders = true
  s3_folder_names = var.s3_folder_names
  environment = var.environment
  s3_bucket_name = var.s3_bucket_name
  force_destroy = true
  bucket_replication_enabled = true
  tags = local.common_tags
  providers = {
    aws.main_region = aws.main_region
    aws.secondary_region = aws.secondary_region
  }
}
```

I am facing problem because count variable can only be set once in resource block. Here is the scenario that is cauing problems:

1. If
   `var.s3_folder_names < aws_s3_bucket.s3bucket.*.id`.
   Then I will not be able to access all the elements of S3 bucket list as shown below

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "folders" {
    count = var.create_folders ? length(var.s3_folder_names) : 0
    **bucket  = element(aws_s3_bucket.s3bucket.*.id, count.index)**
    acl    = "private"
    key    = format("%s/",var.s3_folder_names[count.index])
    source = "/dev/null"
}
```

Hence because of this I will not be able to create these folders inside all of the buckets. The only goal is to create same set of folder structure within all of those buckets.
Any help would be truly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why even create folders? You don't need to.

Comment: Did not understand. I know that their are no folder inside S3 but objects. But from naked eye we work with them and manage them as folders. Hence, I need to create sub-directories with hierarchies inside my each of the S3 buckets using terraform. @jarmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **combined data structure**, e.g.:

```
locals {

  buckets_and_folders = merge([
    for bucket in var.s3_bucket_name:
      {
        for folder in var.s3_folder_names:
        "${bucket}-${folder}" => {
          bucket = bucket
          folder = folder
        }
      }
  ]...)

}
```

Then you would iterate over this structure using `for_each`:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "folders" {

    for_each = var.create_folders ? local.buckets_and_folders : {}

    bucket  = each.value.bucket
    acl    = "private"
    key    = format("%s/", each.value.folder)
    source = "/dev/null"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did try out your way of doing it but I am getting the error as show below:

var.s3_bucket_name is list of string with 1 element
var.s3_folder_names is list of string with 1 element
Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got
"tuple".

Comment: @HemantKumar Did you forget about `...` at the end of merge?

Comment: It was my mistake as I often confuse terraform but now I get it as these '...'  are for unpacking arguments right?

Comment: Thanks for the help. it works like charm.

Comment: @HemantKumar No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: Hi @Marcin How do we use this code if we wanted to create different folders on each bucket? any help would be appreciated.